# Tool tip on Header of Backgrid Table

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backgrid

I am using backgrid to display a table. I want to show tool tip on header of the table.

can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extends Backgrid.HeaderRow

```
  Backgrid.HeaderRow = Backgrid.HeaderRow.extend({
    render: function() {
      var that = this;
      Backgrid.HeaderRow.__super__.render.apply(this, arguments);
      _.each(this.columns.models, function(modelValue) {
        if (modelValue.get('toolTip')) that.$el.find('.' + modelValue.get('name')).attr('title', modelValue.get('toolTip'))
      });
      return this;
    }
  });
```

And in columns pass **toolTip**

```
var pageableGrid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: [{
    // enable the select-all extension
    name: "",
    cell: "select-row",
    headerCell: "select-all",
    toolTip:"test tool tip"
  }].concat(columns),
  collection: pageableTerritories
});
```